# json object usage with ajax returned array

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I have a problem with the returned array from ajax call.

the array is encrypted using json. it is as below

```
while ($found_course = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

    $info[] = array(
        'code' => $found_course['course_code'],
        'name' => $found_course['course_name']   );

}
echo json_encode($info); //this is returned to javascript
```

then the problem is that I am unable to use the above array returned in javascript. I tried using the $.each method but to no avail. the eval() also do not work as it give output as [object object]. Can someone please help me with this.

All I want is to be able to acces the code and the name of the course saperately

Thanks.

Comment: Can you also post your javascript?

Comment: what is the structure of your JSON? how it gets to javascript is not really relevant.

Comment: nit-picky: it's json-encoded, not encrypted.

Answer (score 3):

Just loop through it with `for()`

```
for (var c in myAjaxArray){
    myAjaxArray[c].code; // contains the code
    myAjaxArray[c].name // contains the name
}
```

Make sure you set the dataType in the jQuery ajax call to "JSON" to make sure you have a json Object. Or use the `$.getJSON()` function.

Comment: i would suggest using `var c` instead of `c` to avoid creating a global.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var data = <?= json_encode($info); ?>;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var item = data[i];
  alert(item["code"] + " / " + item["name"]);
}
<script>
```

Comment: This is the structure of the javascript

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the data you need.  Not sure how you tried using $.each but it should be in your success function on your ajax call.  Also make sure the datatype is set to json.

```
success: function(data){
  $(data).each(function(idx,val){
     alert(val.code + " " + val.name);
  })
}
```